# Why is 1/128th note's prefix "semihemidemisemi"?

Tags: terminology, rhythm, history

I've searched throughout the Internet, and so far they only states the fact that 1/64th note is named "hemidemisemiquaver" and 1/128th note is "semihemidemisemiquaver", with no mention *why* the prefix was chosen to be 3 words from 3 different origins and languages, and then loop through them as a cycle as the note value decreases.

What is the historical reason that the note value for 1/64th note and below named in such a non-intuitive and peculiar way?

Comment: *All* name conventions are arbitrary and weird. The ones that are rarely used are particularly weird because there is less pressure for them to get normalized over time. And 128th notes are *extremely* rare - I've been playing for 30 years and I've come upon *one* piece that actually specifies them.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Oxford companion to music the note that is 128 to the semi breve is called a Semihemidemisemiquaver. It also mentions that the English names of the longer names are based upon the old Latin names of the early Middle Ages.

There is also probably some french influence in the word crotchet as the name for a quaver in french is apparently croche (hook)

Also both hemi and demi seem to mean half. So it is just a very elegant way to say quaver semiquaver (Half a quaver) Demiesemiquaver (Half of half a quaver) and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

The prefixes *semi*(latin), *demi*(latin), and *hemi*(greek) all just mean half and they all are applied in that order when referring to something smaller. The order itself seems to be arbitrary is just chosen so you know what the name for the next smaller unit would be and so you don't end up with a random ordering for the name that needs to be memorized.

Here's a list  of names of the 8th note to the 256th note to see this pattern in action:

```
eighth note                 |   quaver
sixteenth note              |   semiquaver  
thirty-second note          |   demisemiquaver  
sixty-fourth note           |   hemidemisemiquaver
hundred twenty-eighth note  |   semihemidemisemiquaver
two-hundred fifty-sixth note|   demisemihemidemisemiquaver
```

Comment: Is there though some historic reason why that is so?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic I've looked for this before, but everything I've found just seems like it's tradition in the ordering.

Comment: Surely it's easier to change the tempo marking to twice its original stated, when writing, so the smallest doesn't need to feature?

Comment: @Tim Yes, but it does exist.